# How do I Use 'IF EXIST' in a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I need to run a Windows batch file to check for the existence of a bunch of files. I wrote the following  batch file code:

```
dir

if exist {"help/user/Content/learning_home.htm"} { echo file exists} ELSE {echo File Deleted}

if exist {"./archibus.war"} {echo File not deleted!} ELSE {echo File Deleted}
if exist {"./build.xml"} { echo file exists} ELSE {echo File Deleted}
```

When I execute the batch file the directory listing gets displayed correctly but the rest of the commands just get displayed back to the command line.

I get the feeling I'm missing something basic. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular parentheses instead of curly brackets.

```
if exist "help/user/Content/learning_home.htm" (echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)

if exist "./archibus.war" (echo File not deleted!) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
if exist "./build.xml" (echo file exists) ELSE (echo File Deleted)
```